# app router next js avoid the default layout and use our own page layout?

Tags: javascript, next.js, layout, app-router

I used a default layout in layout.jsx and as props, I passed all my other pages as children,
in page router, we could config router path to define which layout should be used but in this new system, I don't know how to code it.

```
import "./globals.css"
import Header from "./components/Header"
import { Inter, Poppins } from "next/font/google"

const inter = Inter({ subsets: ["latin"] })

const poppins = Poppins({
    weight: ["400", "700"],
    subsets: ["latin"],
})
export const metadata = {
    title: "Weather app",
    description: "Author Sayeed Mahdi Mousavi",
    keywords: "weather, teather",
}

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en">
            <body className={poppins.className}>
                <Header />
                {children}
            </body>
        </html>
    )
}
```

also, I have another layout for my weather app layout. the below layout is in my weather app folder with the name of the layout.jsx.

```
import LayoutTailwind from "../components/LayoutTailwind"

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
    return (
        <>
            <LayoutTailwind />
            {children}
        </>
    )
}

export default Layout
```

Answer (score 2):

What I understood from your question is that you need different Layouts for different pages in your app. Is that correct? To do so what you can do is remove your `app.js` Layout file and just add `layout.jsx` in all your other route folders.
Carefully read this doc link for further clarification: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/route-groups#creating-multiple-root-layouts

Thank you! Hope I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

as I found the solution was that, we can make a layout for different pages then for each we add our design and content.

```
export default function Categories() {

  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar />

      <div className="lg:pl-72">
        <Header />

        <main className="py-10">
          <div className="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <div className="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
              <CategoryForm />
              <CategoryTable />
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

and this page

```
import Header from "@/components/Header"
import Sidebar from "@/components/Sidebar"

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <Sidebar />

      <div className="lg:pl-72">
        <Header />

        <main className="py-10">
          <div className="px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
            <p>Your content goes here</p>
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

No, we can have our layout on different pages.